# How to create notes using EWS Managed API 2.0

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Even looking into [MSDN's Exchange 2013 - 101 Code Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c), I could not find an example creating notes using EWS Managed API 2.0. On [Folders and items in EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535505%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#bk_item), the most appropriate item type seems to me *PostItem* but my test failed trying to create such items in Notes folder. Or, is it possible there is no API for creating notes in this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PostItem isn't the same as a note in the Notes folder. PostItem's represent items with a message class of `IPM.Post`. Notes, on the other hand, use the message class `IPM.StickyNote`. The managed API has no direct support for these items. You can retrieve them as `EmailMessage` objects, and you can even create them as `EmailMessage` objects if you manually set the required properties. Glen has a good write-up on his blog: http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2009/07/creating-sticky-notes-in-ews-managed.html

Comment: Thanks, I found [this C# example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/df69d01c-1b9b-4dea-8ebd-19e376ca2b4b/e2007ewsmac-how-can-i-create-a-sticky-note-with-the-ews-managed-api).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PostItem, they should do what you want. [PostItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.postitem_members(v=exchg.80).aspx)

*Sample*

```
var items = new List<PostItem>();

for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
{
    var m = new PostItem(service);
    m.Subject = "Note " + i.ToString();
    m.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, "A test note");
    m.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so PostItem should be used. I tried to create notes in WellKnownFolderName.Notes folder but I got the error "Cannot create a post item in a folder that is not a mail folder"...

Comment: What happens, if you dont set any folder?

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Do you know Folder.Bind method?

Comment: Not exactly. Could you post your code in the question please?

Comment: Sure,
`var items = new List<PostItem>();
for (int i = 0; i != maxItems; ++i)
{
    var m = new PostItem(service);
    m.Subject = "Note " + i.ToString();
    m.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, "A test note");
    items.Add(m);
}

var folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Notes, new PropertySet());
var responses = service.CreateItems(items, folder.Id, MessageDisposition.SendOnly, SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);`MessageDisposition.SendOnly, SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);`

Comment: I added an untested code snipped to my answer. Please try it out.

Comment: I tried that but the folder containing the notes is Drafts, not Notes :| If I use m.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Notes) I get the same error. Perhaps the title should be changed to "How to create notes using EWS Managed API 2.0 in Notes folder".

Answer (score 0):

```
var guid = new Guid("0006200E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
var colour = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(guid, 0x8B00, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
var width = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(guid, 0x8B02, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
var height = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(guid, 0x8B03, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
var left = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(guid, 0x8B04, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
var top = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(guid, 0x8B05, MapiPropertyType.Integer);

var items = new List<EmailMessage>();
for (int i = 0; i != maxItems; ++i)
{
    var m = new EmailMessage(service);
    m.Subject = "Note " + i.ToString();
    m.ItemClass = "IPM.StickyNote";
    m.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, "A test note");
    m.SetExtendedProperty(colour, 1);
    m.SetExtendedProperty(width, 200);
    m.SetExtendedProperty(height, 166);
    m.SetExtendedProperty(left, 200);
    m.SetExtendedProperty(top, 200);
    items.Add(m);
}

var folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Notes, new PropertySet());
var responses = service.CreateItems(items, folder.Id, MessageDisposition.SaveOnly, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```